# i want to print all the messages in logfile

Tags: python, logging

I have created a log file and only error and critical messages are appearing as output I have to display all the messages

```
import logging
        Log_format="%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
        # create and configure logger
        logging.basicConfig(filename="logfile.log",
                            filemode='w',
                            format=Log_format,
                            level=logging.ERROR)
        logger=logging.getLogger()
        # test messages
        logger.error("first logging message")
        logger.debug("Harmless debug Message")
        logger.info("Just an information")
        logger.warning("Its a Warning")
        logger.error("Did you try to divide by zero")
        logger.critical("Internet is down")
```

Comment: i think you need to change your logging level.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels

Comment: Explain please what you mean. I don't think your question is understandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the threshold of `logger` to `DEBUG`..

```py
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `logging.basicConfig` you have requested

```
level=logging.ERROR
```

thus only `ERROR` and more severe will be saved (see [`logging` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels) for hierarchy of levels), if you wish to have all set `level` to `logging.DEBUG` (least severe of all you have used) or `logging.NOTSET`